# Smoothing geom_ribbon

Tags: ggplot2

I've created a plot with geom_line and geom_ribbon (image 1) and the result is okay, but for the sake of aesthetics, I'd like the line and ribbon to be smoother. I know I can use geom_smooth for the line (image 2), but I'm not sure if it's possible to smooth the ribbon.I *could* create a geom_smooth line for the top and bottom lines of the ribbon (image 3), but is there anyway to fill in the space between those two lines?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a fine balance between visual appeal and faithfulness to the data.  If you use geom_smooth(), it has options such as method = "gam" and se = TRUE that might help.

Comment: For smaller samples geom_smooth invokes loess regression. You could try loess regression to compute "smooth" points in between and call `geom_ribbon` with those in-between points.  cf http://r-statistics.co/Loess-Regression-With-R.html

Comment: Someone voted to close as off-topic. given that @IsabellaGhement started to discuss whether one should smoothe point data or that was unfaithfull and that gam and loess were proposed, I see this as on topic.

Comment: @Bernhard: I agree that this is an 'on topic' question and an interesting one as well.  I have no control over what other people vote but do find it frustrating when worthy questions are shut down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A principled way to achieve what you want is to fit a GAM model to your data using the gam() function in mgcv and then apply the predict() function to that model over a finer grid of values for your predictor variable. The grid can cover the span defined by the range of observed values for your predictor variable.  The R code below illustrates this process for a concrete example.

```
# load R packages
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)

# simulate some x and y data 
# x = predictor; y = response
x <- seq(-10, 10, by = 1) 
y <- 1 - 0.5*x - 2*x^2 + rnorm(length(x), mean = 0, sd = 20)
d <- data.frame(x,y)

# plot the simulated data 
ggplot(data = d, aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point(size=3)

# fit GAM model
m <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = d) 

# define finer grid of predictor values
xnew <- seq(-10, 10, by = 0.1) 

# apply predict() function to the fitted GAM model
# using the finer grid of x values
p <- predict(m, newdata = data.frame(x = xnew), se = TRUE) 
str(p) 

# plot the estimated mean values of y (fit) at given x values
# over the finer grid of x values;
# superimpose approximate 95% confidence band for the true 
# mean values of y at given x values in the finer grid
g <- data.frame(x = xnew, 
            fit = p$fit,
            lwr = p$fit - 1.96*p$se.fit, 
            upr = p$fit + 1.96*p$se.fit)

head(g) 

theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(data = g, aes(x, fit)) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "lightblue") + 
geom_line() + 
geom_point(data = d, aes(x, y), shape = 1)
```

This same principle would apply if you were to fit a polynomial regression model to your data using the lm() function.

Comment: That would be so nice to have an extended `geom_ribbon` in which this process is implemented and simply driven by a parameter `smooth`!